# How to make angular material checkbox unchecked by default?

Tags: angularjs

How do I keep the checkbox as unchecked by default?  This is my partial html view.

```
<md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="mailingSameAsPermanent" ng-checked="false"><!--ng-change="click()">-->
                        Tick if your mailing address is the same as your permanent address
                    </md-checkbox>
                    {{someinput}}
```

I don't have anything in my angular controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize `$scope.mailingSameAsPermanent = false` in the conroller. or in the html as

`<md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="mailingSameAsPermanent" ng-init="mailingSameAsPermanent = false"></md-checkbox>`

Comment: Will you please provide a jsFiddle or Plunkr link so that I can edit that

Answer (score 0):

**:: In Controller ::**

```
$scope.checkbox = false;
```

**:: HTML ::**

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
            Checkbox 1: {{ checkbox }}
          </md-checkbox>
```